# How can I prove the hypersurface $M$ is neither convex nor concave?

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis

The question is so simple: how can I prove that $M$ (as defined below) is neither convex nor concave (in the real sense)?

The point here is to define a new notion of convexity, the *complex convexity*, in contrast with the real one; so this example should exhibits a surface $M$ for which, although it isn't convex/concave in the real sense, with this new notion we can say that it's *complex convex*.

I try to study the real convexity of $M$ in various ways:

1. With the definition of a convex function in several variables with $f(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)=y_1+2x_2^2-y_2^2-\dots$;
2. Computing the determinant of the Gauss map of the parametrization of the surface (which is the curvature $K$, and we know that the surface is convex iff $K>0$).

But all seems to depend on the (unwritten) terms of degree $\ge3$.

How can I prove that $M$ is neither convex nor concave (in the real sense)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the matter is as follows: the author means "around $0$", in which the terms of degree $\ge3$ are unimportant; so we are looking for a saddle: $z=2x^2-y^2$, which is neither convex nor concave **around zero**.